# "Project is not fully initialized with the default service accounts." Error in brand new account on first project?

Tags: gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

i just signed up for Google Could Engine and started the most basic container engine quickstart on a brand new project:

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/quickstart

a few steps in it has me run this command

```
gcloud container clusters create example-cluster
```

which errors out:

```
$ gcloud container clusters create example-cluster
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=503, message=Project hello-world-161713 is not fully initialized with the default service accounts. Please try again later.
```

so far, "trying again later" has not helped: it's been doing this every time for the past few hours.

as usual, Google has no obvious way of getting help in any timely manner, and Googling the error turns up nothing useful.

kind of a long shot but i found a link sending me over here on one of their pages (great support guys) so figured i'd give it a shot. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Container Engine API needs to be enabled, and unfortunately that error message is not correct (trying again later won't help).

If you visit the Google Container Engine page in the wb console https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list it should enable Google Container Engine. Make sure you select the project you're using with the quickstart.  You can create your cluster from that page too if you'd prefer.

You can also enable the Container Engine API manually here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/container.googleapis.com/overview

Comment: thanks, i managed to figure it out... but, yeah, the error message is pretty useless. hopefully this will help others that have the same issue.

Comment: The error message will be fixed. Thanks for persevering!